# Problems with using javascript variable in css field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one question about using variable (time2 in my case) in data-title CSS field.
This is example what i need : http://jsfiddle.net/9oydvza0/1/
What shall i do that this variable takes value id time2?

Code from link :
CSS:

```
<style>
.photo4 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.photo4:hover:after {
    display: block;
    content: attr(data-title-id);
    position: absolute;
    left: 120%;
    bottom: -250%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #003399;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
     document.getElementById("time2").innerHTML = "ololo";
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p id="time2"></p>
<div style="width:10px; float:left; padding-top:20px;">
    <div class="photo4" data-title-id="time2">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" width="22" height="22px" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is your problem ?

Comment: do you want `css selector` for `time2` or something else?

Comment: `#time2`? I don't really get your question...

Comment: i'm need when i take the mouse in the picture they show me text variable time2 (ololo in my case)

Comment: you have to set the attrib, you can't point to another element for the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS when you are hovering on `class photo4` you are showing its `data-title-id contents,` which you have set to `time2` in your html,So definately it will show `time2`,
So either set it to  `<div class="photo4" data-title-id="ololo">` 
OR if you want to set it dynamically with the `content of id time2`
then do this

```
var myDiv=document.getElementById("time2")
myDiv.innerHTML = "ololo";

document.querySelector('.photo4').setAttribute("data-title-id", myDiv.innerHTML);
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jhaRoshan/9oydvza0/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-title-id]').innerHTML = "ololo";
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm not understand how i can use this, can you show me in example? 
http://jsfiddle.net/9oydvza0/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with jquery you can use like below.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".photo4").attr("data-title-id","ololo");
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/9oydvza0/3/)